# PC reboots after "Welcome to Grub" unless booted from BIOS

Tags: linux, boot, debian, bios, grub

I have a Linux machine running on an ASUS P8H77-I.

The boot drive is correctly set in the BIOS. If I let it boot normally, I see the `Welcome to Grub` line, then it reboots, and repeats forever.

If I hit F2 and go to BIOS boot device selector, then choose the exact same drive as default, it boots correctly. I get the same "Welcome to Grub" line, but then the Grub menu appears.

My feeling is that this is some sort of race condition, and something is not initialised prior to getting to Grub, and it crashes and reboots.  Going via the BIOS boot selector gives enough time for it to work. I tried putting PXE boot first to see if this timing out would give it enough time, but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

If you have any ideas, please let me know what additional information might help.

Boot info is here: http://paste.debian.net/79706/

`/dev/sdc` is the boot disk with Grub installed.

Comment: Additional helpful information to supply: The firmware unit number (0x80, 0x81, 0x82, etc.) of the disc unit in each case.  The output of [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) or an equivalent tool.

Comment: How would I go about getting the firmware unit number?

Comment: It's tricky, and it really depends from what's available to you.  When I had to do this, I ended up recompiling my MBR bootstrap program with an added print function.  Focus on `Boot-Info` to start with.  It will give other people the ability to write [answers like this](http://superuser.com/a/706630/38062).

Comment: Ok, added. http://paste.debian.net/79706/